# How to test text nodes rendered with React using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test with an element has some text. The element is rendered by a React component.

The test code looks like this:

```
el = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.test')
txt = el.text
self.assertNotEqual("", txt, "No Text")
```

The React component has something like this in  a render method:

```
<td><span class=".test">TEST WORDS</span></td>
```

The test sometimes passes and sometimes fails. The element is always found (otherwise it would error on that line). But sometimes the element has text and sometimes it doesn't.

I tried using componentDidMount to set a class on a page element and I don't run the test code until this element is found - thus proving that I am only running the test after the Component has rendered. And the css_selector establishes as I say that the span element in on the page.

Putting a `time.sleep(1)` in the code fixes it.

So the conclusion is that React thinks it has rendered the Component but the text is not yet rendered into the DOM. (The test runs before this part has happened). I can fix this by polling the element for a while to see if the text is rendered.

But I just wondered if my understanding is correct and is this a known problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by polling for the following:

browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.testElement:not(:empty)')

Once the text has arrived on the DOM that gives me 1 (the element it finds).

Comment: This should be in the original question, not listed as an answer.

Comment: So does that mean that the problem is solved? If so, please accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found the right CSS selector but I don't know how you are "polling" since you didn't provide the code used. You should look into Expected Conditions. It's built to do things like this... wait for a certain condition to be true. In this case you would probably want to use `text_to_be_present_in_element`.

You can find more info and some examples [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html) and many other places.